# Prove that the Green´s Function satisfy the Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta, greens-function

Prove that the Green´s Function:

$$G(t,t´)=\theta(t-t´) \dfrac{\sin{[(t-t´)(\omega_0^2-\gamma^2)^{1/2}}]}{(\omega_0^2-\gamma^2)^{1/2}}\cdot e^{-\gamma(t-t´)}  \tag{1}$$ satisfy the Differential Equation: $$\left(\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2}+2\gamma\dfrac{d}{dt}+\omega_0^2\right)G(t,t´)=\delta(t-t´) \tag{2}$$

---

---

Starting with the equation:
$$\ddot{x}(t)+2\gamma\dot{x}(t)+\omega_0^2x(t)=F(t) \tag{3}$$
And using the Fourier transform, we get the given Greens Function:
$$G(t,t´)=\theta(t-t´) \dfrac{\sin{[(t-t´)(\omega_0^2-\gamma^2)^{1/2}}]}{(\omega_0^2-\gamma^2)^{1/2}}\cdot e^{-\gamma(t-t´)} \tag{4}$$

But i dont know how i can show that this Green function satisfy the given equation.

Comment: First: how can a Green's function have a $dt´$ in its formula ?
Second: what sort of thing is $\theta$ ?
Third: why a variable $t'$ if the differential equation is only in $t$ ?
Fourth: ..

Comment: The same question: "how can a Green's function have a $dt'$ in its formula ?" If $\theta$ is a step function, then: hint: Consider the GF in the form
$$G(t-t')=\theta(t-t')f(t)$$
Then
$$\frac{d}{dt}G(t-t')=\delta(t-t')f(t')+\theta(t-t')\frac{d}{dt}f(t)$$
and
$$\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}G(t-t')=\Big(\frac{d}{dt}\delta(t-t')\Big)f(t')+\delta(t-t')\frac{d}{dt}f(t')+\theta(t-t')\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}f(t)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. We know the homogeneous second-order [ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation) with constant coefficients 
   $$\left(\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2}+2\gamma\dfrac{d}{dt}+\omega_0^2\right)x(t) ~=~0 \tag{A}$$
   has complete solution
   $$x(t)~=~\sum_{\pm}C_{\pm}\exp\left\{\lambda_{\pm}t\right\},\tag{B}$$
   where 
   $$\lambda_{\pm}~=~-\gamma\pm \sqrt{\gamma^2-\omega_0^2}\tag{C} $$
   solves the characteristic equation
   $$  \lambda^2+2\gamma\lambda+\omega_0^2~=~0.\tag{D}$$
2. Adjust the two constants $C_{\pm}$ so that 
   $$ x(0)~=~0 \quad\wedge\quad x^{\prime}(0)~=~1. \tag{E}$$
   In other words, 
   $$x(t)~\stackrel{(B)+(C)+(E)}{=}~\frac{\sin\left(t\sqrt{\omega_0^2-\gamma^2}\right)}{\sqrt{\omega_0^2-\gamma^2}} e^{-\gamma t}. \tag{F} $$
3. Define the retarded [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_function) as 
   $$G(t)~:=~\theta(t) x(t).\tag{G}$$
4. Show with above properties (E) that
   $$G^{\prime}(t)~\stackrel{(E)+(G)}{=}~\theta(t) x^{\prime}(t)\tag{H}$$
   and 
   $$G^{\prime\prime}(t)~\stackrel{(E)+(H)}{=}~\theta(t) x^{\prime\prime}(t)+\delta(t)\tag{I}$$ 
   as [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)).
5. Finally show that the retarded Green's function satisfy OP's second equation
   $$\left(\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2}+2\gamma\dfrac{d}{dt}+\omega_0^2\right)G(t) ~\stackrel{(A)+(G)+(H)+(I)}{=}~\delta(t). \tag{J} $$